# How to get topic probability table from text2vec LDA

Tags: r, lda, text2vec

The LDA topic modeling in the text2vec package is amazing. It is indeed much faster than topicmodel

However, I don't know how to get the probability of each document belongs to each topic as the example below:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4
1   0.001025237 7.89E-05    7.89E-05    7.89E-05
2   0.002906977 0.002906977 0.014534884 0.002906977
3   0.003164557 0.003164557 0.003164557 0.003164557
4   7.21E-05    7.21E-05    0.000360334 7.21E-05
5   0.000804433 8.94E-05    8.94E-05    8.94E-05
6   5.63E-05    5.63E-05    5.63E-05    5.63E-05
7   0.001984127 0.001984127 0.001984127 0.001984127
8   0.003515625 0.000390625 0.000390625 0.000390625
9   0.000748503 0.000748503 0.003742515 0.003742515
10  0.000141723 0.00297619  0.000141723 0.000708617
```

This is the code for text2vec lda

```
ss2 <- as.character(stressor5$weibo)
seg2 <- mmseg4j(ss2)


# Create vocabulary. Terms will be unigrams (simple words).
it_test = itoken(seg2, progressbar = FALSE)
vocab2 <- create_vocabulary(it_test)


pruned_vocab2 = prune_vocabulary(vocab2, 
                                 term_count_min = 10, 
                                 doc_proportion_max = 0.5,
                                 doc_proportion_min = 0.001)


vectorizer2 <- vocab_vectorizer(pruned_vocab2)

dtm_test = create_dtm(it_test, vectorizer2)


lda_model = LDA$new(n_topics = 1000, vocabulary = vocab2, doc_topic_prior = 0.1, topic_word_prior = 0.01)

doc_topic_distr = lda_model$fit_transform(dtm_test, n_iter = 1000, convergence_tol = 0.01, check_convergence_every_n = 10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`doc_topic_distr` is a matrix which contains number of how many times words from document were assigned to particular topic. So you need just to normalize each row by number of words (also you can add `doc_topic_prior` before normalization).

```
library(text2vec)
data("movie_review")
tokens = movie_review$review %>% 
  tolower %>% 
  word_tokenizer
# turn off progressbar because it won't look nice in rmd
it = itoken(tokens, ids = movie_review$id, progressbar = FALSE)
v = create_vocabulary(it) %>% 
  prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.2)
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "lda_c")
doc_topic_prior = 0.1
lda_model = 
  LDA$new(n_topics = 10, vocabulary = v, 
          doc_topic_prior = doc_topic_prior, topic_word_prior = 0.01)

doc_topic_distr = 
  lda_model$fit_transform(dtm, n_iter = 1000, convergence_tol = 0.01, 
                          check_convergence_every_n = 10)
head(doc_topic_distr)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#5814_8   16   18    0   34    0   16   49    0   20    23
#2381_9    4    0    6   20    0    0    6    6    0    28
#7759_3   21   39    7    0    3   47    0   25   21    17
#3630_4   18    7   22   14   19    0   18    0    2    35
#9495_8    4    0   13   17   13   78    3    2   28    25
#8196_8    0    0    0   11    0    8    0    8    8     0
doc_topic_prob = normalize(doc_topic_distr, norm = "l1")
# or add norm first and normalize :
# doc_topic_prob = normalize(doc_topic_distr + doc_topic_prior, norm = "l1")
```

Comment: Thanks for developing and maintaining this terrific package! One question: is it also possible to get a matrix of top words by topics? Similar to how they show in page 15 of this paper [ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf ]?

Comment: Yes, I have it locally. Will push to github soon along with new lda algorithm - warplda.

Comment: As a quick workaround, are the values in `LDA$get_word_vectors()` the term frequencies by topics - and can I just sort them to get frequent words? I am still trying to wrap my head around the LDA class.

Comment: something like `word_topic_counts = lda_model$get_word_vectors()
topic_word_distr = t(word_topic_counts + topic_word_prior) %>% normalize('l1')` should work. Just sort each row - you will get top words for each topic.