# Normalized topic document probabilities text2vec R

Tags: r, text2vec

I am trying to find out the topic document probabilities after running the lda model using text2vec package in R.

Following commands generate the model:

```
lda_model <-  LDA$new(n_topics = n_topics, doc_topic_prior = 0.1, topic_word_prior = 0.01)
doc_topic_distr <- lda_model$fit_transform(x = quantdfm, n_iter = 2000, convergence_tol = 0.00001, n_check_convergence = 10, progressbar = FALSE)
```

quantdfm is the dtm using quanteda package, which I am plugging it in the $fit_transform method.

I noticed that the doc_topic_distr contains the topic document probabilities (without even asking for normalization). Is this correct? Because on a previous post: [How to get topic probability table from text2vec LDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826292/how-to-get-topic-probability-table-from-text2vec-lda), Dmitriy Selivanov has asked to derive such probabilities using:

```
doc_topic_prob = normalize(doc_topic_distr, norm = "l1")
```

whereas when I use the same command as above, doc_topic_distr and doc_topic_prob have the same values (I thought the former contains integers as opposed to fractions in the latter).

Please suggest if this is the expected behavior of the code, or I have missed something here.

Thanks.

Comment: What does documentation say?

Comment: Pg 24 says doc_topic_distribution is a dense matrix with rows as documents and columns as topics. Row sum should add to 1. So it seems that this is already normalized. Please comment if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the up to date documentation LDA `fit_transform` returns topic probabilities.